# Get first time occurence in a pandas dataframe indexed with datetime

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe that represent scores from player in a game, indexed by time:

```
             player_id
2016-03-01   873970260
2016-03-02  8470693237
2016-03-02   221785899
2016-03-03   569452661
2016-03-04   221785899
2016-03-04  8276343674
```

I'd like to add a new column containing a boolean which states if the `player_id` appears for the first time in the time series:

```
             player_id  new_player
day
2016-03-01   873970260        True
2016-03-02  8470693237        True
2016-03-02   221785899        True
2016-03-03   569452661        True
2016-03-04   221785899       False
2016-03-04  8276343674        True
```

`True` means "never seen before", `False` means "already scored in the past".

What would be the fastest way? Using `isin` on slices (i.e. comparing `dataframe[day]` to `dataframe[:day-1]`)?

Here is how I build the sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

gamedf = pd.DataFrame([873970260,8470693237,221785899,569452661,221785899,8276343674],
    columns=['player_id'],
    index=[dt.datetime(2016, 3, 1), dt.datetime(2016, 3, 2), dt.datetime(2016, 3, 2), dt.datetime(2016, 3, 3), dt.datetime(2016, 3, 4), dt.datetime(2016, 3, 4)])
```

Comment: You have extra rows in the second dataframe.

Comment: my bad, just fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) to create a boolean series of the values that are duplicates and invert using `~`:

```
In [72]:
df['new_player'] = ~df['player_id'].duplicated()
df

Out[72]:
             player_id new_player
day                              
2016-03-01   873970260       True
2016-03-02  8470693237       True
2016-03-02   221785899       True
2016-03-03   873970260      False
2016-03-03   423970290       True
2016-03-04   221785899      False
2016-03-04  8276343674       True
```

Using your `gamedf` code:

```
In [74]:
gamedf['new_player'] = ~gamedf['player_id'].duplicated()
gamedf

Out[74]:
             player_id new_player
2016-03-01   873970260       True
2016-03-02  8470693237       True
2016-03-02   221785899       True
2016-03-03   569452661       True
2016-03-04   221785899      False
2016-03-04  8276343674       True
```